# unset() not working inside class methods

Tags: php, unset

I have a class say, `Foo` that has a `json` string property named `bar`: [[PHP Fiddle Link]](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6b8d50ce0620a839aaa3a5a8620330f81b0d6a60)

```
<?php


class Foo {

    public $bar = '{"1455260079":"Tracking : #34567808765098767 USPS","1455260723":"Delivered","1455261541":"Received Back"}';

    public function getBar(){
        return (array) json_decode($this->bar);
    }

    public function remove($timestamp){

        $newBar = $this->getBar();

        print_r($newBar);

        unset($newBar[$timestamp]);

        print_r($newBar); 

        $this->bar = json_encode($newBar);

    }

}
```

Now, to remove an element from bar, I am doing the following, I cannot figure out why it it not deleting:

```
$foo = new Foo();
$foo->remove("1455261541");
echo $foo->bar;
```

prints out:

```
Array
(
    [1455260079] => Tracking : #34567808765098767 USPS
    [1455260723] => Delivered
    [1455261541] => Received Back
)
Array
(
    [1455260079] => Tracking : #34567808765098767 USPS
    [1455260723] => Delivered
    [1455261541] => Received Back
)
{"1455260079":"Tracking : #34567808765098767 USPS","1455260723":"Delivered","1455261541":"Received Back"}
```

What's the reason behind this? Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try below solution, i just changed `getBar` function and added one more parameter in `json_decode` function:

```
class Foo {

    public $bar = '{"1455260079":"Tracking : #34567808765098767 USPS","1455260723":"Delivered","1455261541":"Received Back"}';

    public function getBar(){
        return json_decode($this->bar, true);
    }

    public function remove($timestamp){

        $newBar = $this->getBar();

        print_r($newBar);

        unset($newBar[$timestamp]);

        print_r($newBar);

        $this->bar = json_encode($newBar);

    }

}

$foo = new Foo();
$foo->remove("1455261541");
echo $foo->bar;
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [1455260079] => Tracking : #34567808765098767 USPS
    [1455260723] => Delivered
    [1455261541] => Received Back
)
Array
(
    [1455260079] => Tracking : #34567808765098767 USPS
    [1455260723] => Delivered
)
{"1455260079":"Tracking : #34567808765098767 USPS","1455260723":"Delivered"}
```

Comment: Hmm, that works cool! It's so strange that we cannot unset a damn array with keys! Thanks.

Comment: array type casting using `(array)` will convert keys into string see the var_dump of array in your original code